# Stanford CoreNLP- Text to XML

Tags: java, stanford-nlp

Can somebody please provide me with the Java implementation of Stanford CoreNLP to convert a text file to XML file. The same thing that I can do with

```
java -cp stanford-corenlp-2012-05-22.jar;stanford-corenlp-2012-05-22-models.jar;xom.jar;joda-time.jar -Xmx3g edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP -annotators tokenize,ssplit,pos,lemma,ner,parse,dcoref -file input.txt
```

in command line.

Comment: The source code or doing it in a java application?

Comment: the source code for converting an input.txt to input.txt.xml. The code that does the same task as the command i posted does when run in command line. Means like using Stanford CoreNLP API for doing this in Java program or something else that can be done to fulfill the purpose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In java you might call it thus:

```
import edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP;
```

...

```
StanfordCoreNLP.main(new String[] {
    "-annotators", "tokenize,ssplit,pos,lemma,ner,parse,dcoref",
    "-file", "input.txt" });
```

*(If this suffices)*

Answer (score 4):

Joop's answer certainly works, but in case you want to dig a little bit deeper rather than using the main method as your API, here's a complete sample that shows writing the sentence analysis in XML to a file.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

import edu.stanford.nlp.io.*;
import edu.stanford.nlp.ling.*;
import edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.*;
import edu.stanford.nlp.trees.*;
import edu.stanford.nlp.util.*;

public class StanfordCoreNlpDemo {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    PrintWriter out;
    if (args.length > 1) {
      out = new PrintWriter(args[1]);
    } else {
      out = new PrintWriter(System.out);
    }
    PrintWriter xmlOut = null;
    if (args.length > 2) {
      xmlOut = new PrintWriter(args[2]);
    }

    StanfordCoreNLP pipeline = new StanfordCoreNLP();
    Annotation annotation;
    if (args.length > 0) {
      annotation = new Annotation(IOUtils.slurpFileNoExceptions(args[0]));
    } else {
      annotation = new Annotation("Kosgi Santosh sent an email to Stanford University. He didn't get a reply.");
    }

    pipeline.annotate(annotation);
    pipeline.prettyPrint(annotation, out);
    if (xmlOut != null) {
      pipeline.xmlPrint(annotation, xmlOut);
    }
    // An Annotation is a Map and you can get and use the various analyses individually.
    // For instance, this gets the parse tree of the first sentence in the text.
    List<CoreMap> sentences = annotation.get(CoreAnnotations.SentencesAnnotation.class);
    if (sentences != null && sentences.size() > 0) {
      CoreMap sentence = sentences.get(0);
      Tree tree = sentence.get(TreeCoreAnnotations.TreeAnnotation.class);
      out.println();
      out.println("The first sentence parsed is:");
      tree.pennPrint(out);
    }
  }

}
```

Comment: Somehow this is not working anymore or I am doing something wrong. The import for `StanfordCoreNLP` is not working anymore, because it does not appear to be in the `*.pipeline.*` package. But i cannot find it anywhere else within the project.

Comment: Still works for me! (With the current v3.3.1.) Maybe your CLASSPATH isn't right?

Answer (score 0):

Use StanfordCoreNlpDemo.java in the downloaded [CoreNLP's zip](http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/stanford-corenlp-full-2014-06-16.zip)